# Tokenize arithmetic expression in C

Tags: algorithm, c, calculator, lexical-analysis

This program tokenizes an arithmetic expression specified in infix notation. It is one of my personal projects and I would love to receive expert advice.

After compiling, you can run the program with one command-line argument:

```sh
$ tokenize <arith_expr>
```

This is an example of running the program:

```sh
$ tokenize "3^2 + 4.5 * (-2 - 1)"
```

The tokenizer currently supports these operators `+ - * / ^`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Can store an operator or an operand */
struct token {
    char operator;
    float operand;
};

/* Check if given token is an operator */
bool is_operator(char token)
{
    if (token == '+' ||
        token == '-' ||
        token == '*' ||
        token == '/' ||
        token == '^')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/* Remove all spaces from string */
void rmspaces(char *str)
{
    const char *dup = str;
    do {
        while (isspace(*dup))
            ++dup;
    } while (*str++ = *dup++);
}

/* Return first token of given arithmetic expression */
struct token *tokenize(char **expr)
{
    static bool op_allowed = false;
    struct token *token = malloc(sizeof *token);
    if (!token) {
        printf("Error: memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (op_allowed && is_operator(*expr[0])) {
        token->operator = *expr[0];
        ++(*expr);
        op_allowed = false;
    } else if (!op_allowed && *expr[0] == '(') {
        token->operator = *expr[0];
        ++(*expr);
    } else if (op_allowed && *expr[0] == ')') {
        token->operator = *expr[0];
        ++(*expr);
    } else {
        char *rest;
        token->operand = strtof(*expr, &rest);
        token->operator = '\0';
        if (*expr == rest) {
            printf("Invalid expression\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(*expr, rest);
        op_allowed = true;
    }

    return token;
}

/* Handle command line arguments */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage:   %s <arith_expr>\n"
            "Example: %s \"5 2 3 * +\"\n",
            argv[0], argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *expr = argv[1];
    rmspaces(expr);
    struct token *token;
    while (expr[0] != '\0') {
        token = tokenize(&expr);
        if (token->operator == '\0') // token is operand
            printf("%f\n", token->operand);
        else
            printf("%c\n", token->operator);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `is_operator` function can be rewritten as

```
return token == '+' || token == '-' || token == '*' || token == '/' || token == '^';
```

Much cleaner, in my opinion.

---

The program has a memory leak. Your `tokenize` function allocates a `struct token` on the heap, but the object is never freed.

Better yet, instead of returning a `struct token*`, just return a `struct token`. The struct certainly isn't large enough to warrant an allocation on the heap.

---

Instead of checking whether `token` is an operand by comparing `operator` to `0`, use an enum.

```
typedef enum { 
       TokenType_Operator, 
       TokenType_Operand 
} token_type;
```

Then your `token` struct can consist of the `token_type` enum, and an union.

```
struct token
{
   token_type type;
   union {
       char operator;
       float operand;
   } data;
};
```

If you're using C11, you don't even need to name the union anything.

---

As a next step, try to implement a tokenizer that tokenizes in one pass. Right now, your tokenizer 1) removes whitespace (which involves a linear pass) and 2) copies of the rest of the string after the tokenizing an operand into the original buffer. If you have a large buffer, this could become a bottleneck.

A common way to implement a tokenizer is using a DFA (deterministic finite automata). In fact, a DFA is a starting point for most handwritten lexers.

Comment: The tokenizer is part of [a calculator I programmed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257409) and the points you mentioned are very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
while (isspace(*dup))
```

has a common mistake, but it is *wrong*. For example Linux manuals have this in their notes:

> NOTES
> The  standards  require that the argument c for these functions is either EOF or a value that is representable in the type unsigned
> char.  If the argument c
> is of type char, it must be cast to unsigned char, as in the following example:
>
> ```
> char c;
> ...
> res = toupper((unsigned char) c);
> ```
>
> This is necessary because char may be the equivalent of signed char, in which case a byte where the top bit is set would be sign
> extended when converting to
> int, yielding a value that is outside the range of unsigned char.

---

For `isoperator` I would use

```
return token && strchr("+-*/^", token);
```

`strchr` returns the pointer to the first occurrence of the given character in the string, and NULL pointer if not found. The `token &&` part is to make sure that `token` is not the NUL character, because `strchr` does return a pointer to the terminator if 2nd argument is the NUL character.

Comment: Thanks! I will take your suggestions into consideration.